# Writing trace to file

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have been trying to write the results by setting [`*trace-output*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_debug_.htm#STtrace-outputST) to file-generated stream like this

```
(setf *trace-output* (open "log.txt"))
```

but this fails with `Error: Unexpected end of file on #<BASIC-FILE-CHARACTER-INPUT-STREAM`.

So, the question is - is there any way to write results of trace to file ?

Comment: Depending on the implementation that you are using it may already have a built-in utility that writes the result of the trace output directly to a file.

Comment: It's already in the error message: `BASIC-FILE-CHARACTER-INPUT-STREAM`. You are trying to do **OUTPUT** on an **INPUT** stream. You need to create an **OUTPUT** stream - as in Barmar's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(setf *trace-output* (open "log.txt" :direction :output))
```

OPEN opens files for input by default.

Comment: I'd `(setf *trace-output* (open "log.txt" :direction :output :if-exists :append))`